# Is there any way to get a substring from a string in Nunjucks templating language?

Tags: nunjucks

If we have value 'cats', I want the substring 'at' (need to delete first and last letters). How can we accomplish that in a Nunjucks template?

Comment: `{{cats.slice(1, -1)}}`. Meow!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this using the JavaScript `slice` method, like so:

```
{{cats.slice(1, -1)}}
```